# how to show or hide form elements using number spinners in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

am recently working on a project in bootstrap which i included an event planner in one of my forms.The question is how can i show or hide a form-group using a number spinner by getting the value of the number spinner.Below is my code.Thanks.

```js
$('select[name="number-spinner"]').on('change',function(){
   var selectedVal=$(this).val();
   switch(selectedVal){
       case '0':
                   $('.day-1').hide();
                   $('.day-2').hide();
       $('.day-3').hide();
       $('.day-4').hide();
       $('.day-5').hide();
       $('.day-6').hide();
       $('.day-7').hide();
             break;
       case '1'://case '2': 
       //Add this into consideration if you have multiple cases where functionality has to be same
                   $('.day-1').show();
       $('.day-2').hide();
       $('.day-3').hide();
       $('.day-4').hide();
       $('.day-5').hide();
       $('.day-6').hide();
       $('.day-7').hide();
             break;
  case '2':
     $('.day-1').hide();
                   $('.day-2').show();
       $('.day-3').hide();
       $('.day-4').hide();
       $('.day-5').hide();
       $('.day-6').hide();
       $('.day-7').hide();
       default: //change this according to your need
                   $('.day-1').hide();
                   $('.day-2').hide();
       $('.day-3').hide();
       $('.day-4').hide();
       $('.day-5').hide();
       $('.day-6').hide();
       $('.day-7').hide();
             break;
   }
});
```

```html
<div id="number-spinner" class="col-sm-3">
<input 
 id="demo0"
   type="text"
   value="0"
   name="demo0"
   data-bts-min="0"
   data-bts-max="7"
   data-bts-init-val=""
   data-bts-step="1"
   data-bts-decimal="0"
   data-bts-step-interval="7"
   data-bts-force-step-divisibility="round"
   data-bts-step-interval-delay="500"
   data-bts-prefix=""
   data-bts-postfix="day(s)"
   data-bts-prefix-extra-class=""
   data-bts-postfix-extra-class=""
   data-bts-booster="true"
   data-bts-boostat="10"
   data-bts-max-boosted-step="false"
   data-bts-mousewheel="true"
   data-bts-button-down-class="btn btn-default"
   data-bts-button-up-class="btn btn-default"
  />

</div>
```

Comment: Change you selector from `('select[name="number-spinner"]')` to `('#demo0)` you are currently selecting `div` where you want to select the `input`.

Comment: still not working @azs06